# npm install fails with Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

while trying to install dependencies for [this](https://github.com/ujjavaldesai07/spring-boot-react-ecommerce-app/tree/master/client) project, `npm install` fails with

```
> npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: ecommerce-app@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"latest" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.11.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!     @material-ui/core@"latest" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @material-ui/core@"^4.0.0" from @material-ui/icons@4.11.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@material-ui/icons
npm ERR!       @material-ui/icons@"latest" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (@material-ui/lab)
npm ERR!   10 more (react-dom, @material-ui/icons, @material-ui/lab, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! redux-form@"^8.3.6" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.4.2" from redux-form@8.3.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/redux-form
npm ERR!     redux-form@"^8.3.6" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/gergo/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/gergo/.npm/_logs/2022-03-17T17_37_09_399Z-debug-0.log
```

**EDIT**

when running `npm install --force`, I got this other error

```
npm ERR! 2 warnings generated.
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/libsass/src/values.cpp:3:
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/libsass/src/values.hpp:4:
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:25: warning: loop variable 'numerator' of type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>' creates a copy from type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>' [-Wrange-loop-analysis]
npm ERR!         for (const auto numerator : numerators)
npm ERR!                         ^
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:14: note: use reference type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char> &' to prevent copying
npm ERR!         for (const auto numerator : numerators)
npm ERR!              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!                         &
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:25: warning: loop variable 'denominator' of type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>' creates a copy from type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>' [-Wrange-loop-analysis]
npm ERR!         for (const auto denominator : denominators)
npm ERR!                         ^
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:14: note: use reference type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char> &' to prevent copying
npm ERR!         for (const auto denominator : denominators)
npm ERR!              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!                         &
npm ERR! 2 warnings generated.
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/binding.cpp:1:
npm ERR! In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:56:
npm ERR! In file included from /Users/gergo/.node-gyp/17.4.0/include/node/node.h:63:
npm ERR! In file included from /Users/gergo/.node-gyp/17.4.0/include/node/v8.h:25:
npm ERR! In file included from /Users/gergo/.node-gyp/17.4.0/include/node/v8-array-buffer.h:12:
npm ERR! In file included from /Users/gergo/.node-gyp/17.4.0/include/node/v8-local-handle.h:12:
npm ERR! /Users/gergo/.node-gyp/17.4.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:563:38: error: no template named 'remove_cv_t' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'remove_cv'?
npm ERR!             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
npm ERR!                                 ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!                                      remove_cv
npm ERR! /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:697:50: note: 'remove_cv' declared here
npm ERR! template <class _Tp> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS remove_cv
npm ERR!                                                  ^
npm ERR! 1 error generated.
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/gergo/Documents/spring-boot-react-ecommerce-app/client/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:520:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/17.4.0/bin/node" "/Users/gergo/Documents/spring-boot-react-ecommerce-app/client/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/gergo/Documents/spring-boot-react-ecommerce-app/client/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v17.4.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

**EDIT**

the second error is thrown while installing node-sass. my node version was not compatible with "node-sass": "^4.14.1".  I have changed node-sass version to be compatible with my node version and this error went away. and the build is successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the second error is thrown while installing node-sass.
my node version (17.4) was not compatible with `"node-sass": "^4.14.1"`

I have changed node-sass version to be compatible with my node version and this error went away. and the build is successful.

Answer (score 16):

For the first error, I tried to install npm with the following 2 commands in Terminal one after another. It fixes for me:

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
npm audit fix --force
```

*N.B: Don't forget to restart the terminal after installing

Comment: this resolved conflicts in peer dependecies.

Comment: This works but doesn't seem like a permanent fix. The next time you try to do `npm i` you get the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting errors because of the `@material-ui/core` which is deprecated see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/core
the new package for material-ui is https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/material.

As they say here https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#update-react-amp-typescript-version

- The minimum supported version of React was increased from v16.8.0 to v17.0.0.

You should consider upgrading your react and material ui, they also changed styling tool to emotion, you'll find more info about in the link above.
Also, they have pretty good migration guides for cases like yours, check https://mui.com/components/data-grid/migration-v4/#migrating-mui-core-from-v4

Temporary alternative can be using force install(`npm install --force`) but I really recommend upgrading your dependencies as otherwise there are no warranties that things will work.

Answer (score 1):

install the dependencies like this:

```
npm install <dependencyname> --force
```

or if you want to install all dependencies at once,

```
npm install --force
```

Comment: I have tried this, it fails with an other error.

Comment: can you share the new error?

Comment: Sure, I have edited the original post and added the new error.

Comment: It doesn't work - fails with another error when I try to reproduce this answer and run the command.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing package management to yarn. At present, most packages already support yarn, and its dependency processing is better.

```
yarn install
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried all the above solutions but when I Removed all the dependencies and install them one by one, It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Is it still failing? for me npm install works without an error using node version 14.16.0

Comment: using higher version node-sass fixed it. thanks. see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71618319/176569

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your `node-sass` version to be compatible with the current LTS version of Node.js.

To do this, change your `package.json` file to include the following (replacing the old declaration).

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1"
  }
}
```

Then, run the following command, and there should be no errors.

```
$ npm install
```

<sub>Ignore the $, it is just to indicate the terminal.</sub>